# Expire date in iOS distribution files

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have just renewed my account at Apple, but I can see my provisioning profiles that currently use for itunes distribution have an expiry date in early July.

Am I correct in that:

1)

All existing apps released before that date will continue working and be downloadable now where I have renewed my iOS developer account? (ie. I do not have to make a new release of them)

2)

It is first when I get past the expiry date I need to create new provisioning profiles for new app releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Correct. Your existing apps in the store will download and install fine. Even if your distribution provisioning profile is expired.

2) You can create a new distribution provisioning profile whenever. As long as it's valid when you upload an update.